# Login form not saving values when login incorrect

Tags: login

I am using a login form created with the following...

```
<?php $args = array(
        'value_remember' => true );
         wp_login_form($args);
?>
```

It works great but if somebody puts an incorrect password in then the page reloads and instead of keeping the username in it is blank.  The person then has to re-enter it, is there anyway to get it to save this value?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L257), the `value_remember` argument sets the "Remember Me" checkbox to `checked`.  It doesn't have anything to do with retaining the username.

So the answer to your question is probably "No".